# Does pre-flight CORS (OPTIONS method) count against the Developer Limits?

Tags: rest-api, limits

Does anybody know if OPTIONS method counts against the limits? I have to make REST queries from JS (browser) CORS environment which does extra Salesforce OPTIONS query.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request